# How to find out which nuget package causes exception?

Tags: c#, nunit

I am trying to implement unit tests in my .net 5.0 project by using `WebApplicationFactory` class and NUnit nugget.

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>
    : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup: class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                d => d.ServiceType ==
                     typeof(DbContextOptions<AppDatabaseContext>));

            services.Remove(descriptor);

            services.AddDbContext<AppDatabaseContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting");
            });

            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
            {
                var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var db = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<AppDatabaseContext>();
                var logger = scopedServices
                    .GetRequiredService<ILogger<CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>>>();

                db.Database.EnsureCreated();

                try
                {
                    Utilities.InitializeDbForTests(db);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the " +
                                        "database with test messages. Error: {Message}", ex.Message);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am creating an instance of `CustomWebApplicationFactory` in my Setup method:

```
public class BaseTests
{
    protected HttpClient _client;
    protected CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> _customWebApplicationFactory;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _customWebApplicationFactory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>();
        _client = _customWebApplicationFactory.CreateClient();
    }
}
```

but when I am calling my tests with `_client.GetAsync("myURL")` I get this error:

> System.MissingMethodException : Method not found:
> 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression DbSetAccessRewritingExpressionVisitor.Rewrite(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IModel, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)'.

I have read about this exception and from what i have found out it occurs when nuget packages are incompatible/too old. I have tried updating all installed nuget packages, but it did not help. If this is error is indeed caused by incompatible nuget package, how do I find out which two are colliding with each other?

Comment: You don't indicate how you are running your tests, i.e. which runner?

Comment: Which runner? I am using NUnit. Is that what you meant by runner?

Comment: NUnit tests can be run from various runners, e.g.: NUnit Console runner, NUnitLite, Visual studio test adapter under the IDE or under vstest.exe, TestCentric GUI, etc.

Comment: I am using JetBrains Rider and i am just running project with NUnit tests. I guess thats the equivalent of 'dotnet test' in console.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue simply by unistalling the NuGet packages which were a pre-release version.